# Nullability of reference types in return type 'T? Manager<T>.Strategy.get' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'T IManager<T>.Strategy.get'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using C# 10 I have:

```
public interface IStrategy<T> where T: Options { 
  T Options { get; }
}

public abstract class Strategy<T> : IStrategy<T> where T : Options {
  public abstract T Options { get; }
}

public interface IManager<T> where T: IStrategy<Options> {
  T Strategy { get; set; }
  Task Run();
}

public class Manager<T> : IManager<T> where T : IStrategy<Options> {

  public String Name { get; set; } 
  public T? Strategy { get; set; }

  public Manager(String name) {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

I am getting the warning:

```
Nullability of reference types in return type of 'T? Manager<T>.Strategy.get' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'T IManager<T>.Strategy.get' (possibly because of nullability attributes).
```

I know that `Strategy` might be null in Manager because it might be set later and not in the constructor.

But Options in Strategy will never be null.

I have been changing `T` to `T?` but I always end up with a warning somewhere.

How to fix this?

Comment: Well no, you can't. Or well you can, but you (rightfully) get a warning. If the parent interface has promised callers the value will not be `null`, who are you to renege on that promise? This means code that calls `IManager<T>.Strategy` could be broken by getting back a `null` value it wasn't expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you are saying in your generics that you don't expect `T` to be null, then you are having a property whose getter (that's `T IManager<T>.Strategy.get`) might return a `null T`: that's the warning you are getting. Using only managed code and not reading externally (and unless you force the use of `null` explicitly), that should never happen (`Strategy` could never return `null`)

You can make it:

```
public class Manager<T> : IManager<T?> where T : IStrategy<Options> 
// Notice the ? in IManager<T?>
```

And the warning should go away, but think if that's what you actually want (that's precisely what nullable reference type annotations are for)

I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccar24